# Using mongo aggregate in meteor to total unlocked/locked in collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

So, I have one collection that stores docs related to a user with a structure like:

```
{_id: "hofjew233332j4", userId: "fhewojfw34324", achievementUnlocked: true };
```

What I want to do is use the aggregate and underscore to be able to group the docs by user id and then calculate what percentage of their records have unlocked set to true such that a resulting doc would look like:

```
{_id: "fhewojfw34324(userId)", unlockPercentage: 40 (achievementUnlocked: true / all docs) }
```

Would I be able to do this while only retrieving the documents once?

Comment: While "possible" it would be very unwise in general. But this also begs the question that "achievements" would seem to be something that should be relatively small. Why not use an array for "unlocked" and one for "locked" and maintain the count vaues for each? That would seem a far more practical model than using seperate documents. It would also save the trouble of aggregating data since you would always be maintaining the totals.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by using separate documents but i'd rather not pollute the user doc with a value that will consistently change. Achievements is actually a quite large data set that could contain 1000's of records per user.

Comment: Then it probably should not contain 1000's of records. Split it up. I've explained my approach with an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First group by count `achievementUnlocked` `true` count and used after that in project to calculate `percentage` as using below aggregation:

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$userId",
        "achievementUnlockedTrueCount": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": {
                    "if": {
                        "$eq": ["$achievementUnlocked", true] //count achievementUnlocked = true count 
                    },
                    "then": 1,
                    "else": 0
                }
            }
        },
        "totalCount": {
            "$sum": 1 // get total count of grouped documents 
        }
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
        "unlockPercentage": {
            "$multiply": [{
                "$divide": ["$achievementUnlockedTrueCount", "$totalCount"] //used this in project to caculate %
            }, 100]
        }
    }
}]).pretty()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally not even bother with aggregation here as the data would seem trivial. It would be far more efficient to maintain an array of "locked" and "unlocked" achievements per user and/or "game" data.

Take a document like this:

```
{
    "_id": "hofjew233332j4", 
    "userId": "fhewojfw34324",
    "gameId": "v3XWHHvFSHwYxxk6H",
    "achievementsCount": 5,
    "locked": ["One","Two","Four","Five"],
    "lockedCount": 4,
    "unlocked": ["Three"]
    "unlockedCount": 1
}
```

So you would initialize per user and "game" here with all "locked" achievements normally, but in this case we will show one already within "unlocked". Also note the "count" fields reflect the number of entries present in each array.

To "unlock" another achievement, then you would simply perform an update to remove from the "locked" array and insert into the "unlocked" array, all while maintaining the "count" values:

```
Achievements.update(
   { 
       "userId": "fhewojfw34324",
       "gameId": "v3XWHHvFSHwYxxk6H",
       "locked": "Four",
       "unlocked": { "$ne": "Four" }
   },
   {
       "$push": { "unlocked": "Four" },
       "$pull": { "locked": "Four" },
       "$inc": {
           "lockedCount": -1,
           "unlockedCount": 1
       }
   }
)
```

Which alters the document to this state:

```
{
    "_id": "hofjew233332j4", 
    "userId": "fhewojfw34324",
    "gameId": "v3XWHHvFSHwYxxk6H",
    "achievementsCount": 5,
    "locked": ["One","Two","Five"],
    "lockedCount": 3,
    "unlocked": ["Three","Four"]
    "unlockedCount": 2
}
```

It's a very simple pattern to follow as each update maintains the correct values and data. If you wanted information such as a "percentage" then this is a simple matter of:

```
Achievements.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "userId": 1,
        "gameId": 1,
        "percentUnlocked": { "$divide": [ "$unlockedCount", "$achivementsCount" ] }
])
```

Or just apply that math in client code instead.

This model also makes "real" aggregations you might want to do a lot simplier, and with a lot more scope to information. Plus, it's much more efficient to calculate as you go, than to require something to "add up" the data as a separate process.

Comment: Im sorry but you seem to be attacking a different problem. I dont need the whole data structure change and trust me when I say there is no way in this case to get around there being 1000's of records. Suffice it to say, with your structure, each doc would be extremely large and would kill the efficiency you may add with having less docs.

Comment: @TDmoneybanks What you **need** to understand here is what you "propose" ultimately needs to follow the same approach. In order to get the "total" and "percentage" in one query, you need to stuff everything into a singular array, then unwind it again to do the other calculations, or accept multiple queries. The first is "impractical" and likely to break limits, the second is "slow". Rethink the design in order to suit what you need to do. I am not taking about 1000's, and I am also demonstrating a clear way to "break that up", which is something you need to consider.

Comment: Thanks for your help but i dont think were on the same page. Sorry if what I asked was confusing or ill formatted.

Comment: @TDmoneybanks It's not confusing. It's just that you are approaching this in the "wrong way", therefore I am sharing some "wisdom" here and showing you something you likely have not conidered. Working with your `true/false` values is just a matter of using the [$cond](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator to tranlate to numeric. I can show the the "wrong way" to do this, but instead I'm offering you a "better" perspective where you can simply maintain the counts on each update. Much faster than aggregating results in retrospect.

Comment: I'm not confused by what your trying to say. I'm telling you that you are no where near as intimate with the data I have as I am and that what your proposing will not work for my use case.

Comment: @TDmoneybanks Yeah well, errm! As the saying goes, *"You can lead a horse to water.."*. You might just consider that I also correctly "tagged" your question, which you did not, and also talk aggregation principles clearly "sounding like" someone who knows what that are talking about. So you cannot be forced to listen but maybe will have to fall down for yourself before you realize the mistake. I can only try to educate.

Comment: i dont think you get it but god do you sound smug. I may not end up doing this very small part due to speed constraints but your solution is absolutely not workable for my data set which you would see if you had access to it. What gives you the idea that your solution is able to fit all use cases?

Comment: @TDmoneybanks Blakes Seven idea that his solution is able to fit all use cases is quite logical. The one case where it wouldn't be suitable is if your bigger document weights more than 16mb, and that make a lot of achievements. Several alternatives with pro/cons: 1) you use a `Cursor.observe()` and build your ratio "on the fly". 2) You use collection hooks and you update a ratio field after each insert/update/delete.

Comment: In the end, it all depends on how many achievements you want too keep track of, if you want your publication to be reactive (afaik `Collection.aggregate()` isn't) and if you plan to scale up to several servers (you then need to run `Cursor.observe()` for each). I guess the most "optimized" solution would be to use @Blakes Seven data structure, except for the aggregation part. It you keep a count, you can as well keep a ratio using collection hooks. This way, you just use a simple and reactive `Collection.find()` and you don't even have to pull out all the achievements every time you publish.

Comment: @Billybobbonnet Her solution :) Hooks mean more udpates firing off, so it's generally a "trade-off". Personally I would "pre-aggregate" with plain aggregation on a periodic basis if I did not need the latest updates all of the time